# can we conclude $f(m)=\sqrt2(\log m)^{1/2}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

If $$f(m)=\sup\{s: s^2/2\leq \log m\}$$
then can we conclude that $f(m)=\sqrt{2}(\log m)^{1/2}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{s^2}{2}\leqslant \log m\iff |s|\leqslant \sqrt{2\log m} $$
Thus $f(m)=\sqrt{2\log m}$.